# Rails collection_select field is repeating entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, collections, updates

In my rails app form, I've the following code for a multi-select:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :frameworks %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :framework_ids, Framework.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true}  %>
</div>
```

It works fine at creation, and it shows correctly the previowsly selected frameworks on edit view.

But when I submit some other updated fields, it repeats the frameworks entries in my database.

For example, if I had selected "framework1", "frameworks2", after updating I've in database "framework1", "frameworks2", "framework1", "frameworks2", and if I update one more time: "framework1", "frameworks2","framework1", "frameworks2","framework1", "frameworks2".

So what should I do to prevent it?

**EDIT:**
The controller is here:

```
@component = Component.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @component.update_attributes(params[:component])
          @component.update_attribute(:numImages, @component.assets.size)
          @component.save

          format.html { redirect_to @component, notice: 'Component was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        else
          format.html { render action: "edit" }
          format.json { render json: @component.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
```

end

By the way, is correct to update :numImages as I do?

Comment: Please provide your controller side code, problem exist there and not on the view page

Comment: I've added the controller part.

Answer (score 0):

For the numImages update (your sub-question), I'd suggest using a before_update method in your Component model.

```
  before_update :set_numimages

  def set_numimages
    numImages = assets.size
  end
```

Also, you're calling update_attributes, update_attribute *and* save on @component. That invokes three save actions. I'd suggest you change it to this and see if the problem persists:

```
@component = Component.find(params[:id])  

respond_to do |format|
  if @component.update_attributes(params[:component])
    format.html { redirect_to @component, notice: 'Component was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @component.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```